# Unable to reinstall PyTables for Python 2.7

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

I am installing Python 2.7 in addition to 2.7. When installing PyTables again for 2.7, I get this error -

- Found numpy 1.5.1 package installed.
  .. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
  You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and
  library can be found by setting the `HDF5_DIR` environment
  variable or by using the `--hdf5` command-line option.

I am not clear on the HDF installation. I downloaded again - and copied it into a /usr/local/hdf5 directory. And tried to set the environement vars as suggested in the PyTable install. Has anyone else had this problem that could help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hdf5 command line option was not stated correctly  ( --hdf5='/usr/local/hdf5' ). Sprinkling print statements in the setup.py made it easier to pin down the problem.

Answer (score 4):

My `HDF5` was installed with homebrew, so setting the environment variable as follows worked for me:  `HDF5_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.8.9`

Comment: Thanks, I did the homebrew install with: `brew tap homebrew/science` along with a `brew install hdf5`, then it worked.

Answer (score 3):

That did not work for me.

On Ubuntu 13.10 -- after downloading the latest hdf5 and the python handles for it I `sudo`'d to create a symbolic link for the header files for hdf5 when the dependent libraries I was using failed to find them -- I'm working with pac bio core libraries for a custom
though using

```
sudo updatedb
```

and

```
locate hdf5
```

did find them in my path after I had downloaded and installed the core libraries and python handles

```
wget http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/hdf5-1.8.12.tar.gz
```

and

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/h/h5py/h5py-2.2.1.tar.gz
```

I had to do the following:

```
export HDF5_DIR=/mnt/hdf5-1.8.12/hdf5/

pip install tables --force
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to install `libhdf5-8` and `libhdf5-serial-dev` first.

Then, for me, the command on Ubuntu was:

`export HDF5_DIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/`

Answer (score 2):

Do the following steps:

1. brew tap homebrew/science
2. brew install hdf5
3. see where hdf5 is installed, it shows at the end of second step
4. export HDF5_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.8.16_1/  (Depending on the location that is installed on your computer)
5. This one worked for me on MAC :-)