# Python ValueError: did not find HDF5 headers

Tags: python, cmd, hdf5, netcdf

I am trying to install rvic in python using its setup.py. When I run the python setup.py install in command prompt, it shows the **Value error: did not find HDF5 headers**.

I tried installing **h5py** too, but still, it's getting the same error.
Any suggestions?

Stackoverflow isnt allowing me to post this so Im adding some more details about this...
rvic is a hydrologic model which is used to estimate the discharge from a basin, I need to perform the routing and for that I'm installing setup.py 
Thanks

```
G:\Rathore\RVIC-master\RVIC-master>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to rvic.egg-info\requires.txt
writing rvic.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to rvic.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to rvic.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'rvic.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'rvic.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying rvic\version.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic
running build_ext
creating build\bdist.win32\egg
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\convert.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\convolution.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\aggregate.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic
\core
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\config.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\co
re
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\convert.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\c
ore
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\convolution_wrapper.py -> build\bdist.win3
2\egg\rvic\core
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\history.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\c
ore
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\log.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\make_uh.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\c
ore
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\multi_proc.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvi
c\core
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\param_file.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvi
c\core
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\plots.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\cor
e
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\pycompat.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\
core
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\read_forcing.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\r
vic\core
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\remap.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\cor
e
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\share.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\cor
e
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\time_utility.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\r
vic\core
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\utilities.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic
\core
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\variables.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic
\core
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\write.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\cor
e
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\core\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\
core
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\parameters.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\version.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\rvic_convolution.pyd -> build\bdist.win32\egg
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\convert.py to convert.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\convolution.py to convolution.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\aggregate.py to aggregate.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\config.py to config.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\convert.py to convert.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\convolution_wrapper.py to convolu
tion_wrapper.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\history.py to history.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\log.py to log.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\make_uh.py to make_uh.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\multi_proc.py to multi_proc.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\param_file.py to param_file.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\plots.py to plots.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\pycompat.py to pycompat.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\read_forcing.py to read_forcing.p
yc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\remap.py to remap.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\share.py to share.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\time_utility.py to time_utility.p
yc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\utilities.py to utilities.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\variables.py to variables.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\write.py to write.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\core\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\parameters.py to parameters.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\version.py to version.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
creating stub loader for rvic_convolution.pyd
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\rvic_convolution.py to rvic_convolution.pyc

creating build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
installing scripts to build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO\scripts
running install_scripts
running build_scripts
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO\scripts
copying build\scripts-2.7\find_pour_points.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO\
scripts
copying build\scripts-2.7\fraction2domain.bash -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
\scripts
copying build\scripts-2.7\rvic -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO\scripts
copying rvic.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying rvic.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying rvic.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying rvic.egg-info\requires.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying rvic.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
writing build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO\native_libs.txt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
rvic.core.convolution_wrapper: module references __file__
creating 'dist\rvic-1.1.1-py2.7-win32.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win32\egg' to
 it
removing 'build\bdist.win32\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing rvic-1.1.1-py2.7-win32.egg
removing 'c:\python27\arcgis10.5\lib\site-packages\rvic-1.1.1-py2.7-win32.egg' (
and everything under it)
creating c:\python27\arcgis10.5\lib\site-packages\rvic-1.1.1-py2.7-win32.egg
Extracting rvic-1.1.1-py2.7-win32.egg to c:\python27\arcgis10.5\lib\site-package
s
rvic 1.1.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing find_pour_points.py script to C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Scripts
Installing fraction2domain.bash script to C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Scripts
Installing rvic script to C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Scripts

Installed c:\python27\arcgis10.5\lib\site-packages\rvic-1.1.1-py2.7-win32.egg
Processing dependencies for rvic==1.1.1
Searching for netCDF4>=1.0.6
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/netCDF4/
Best match: netCDF4 1.4.2
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/aa/b067f3b1a2561f29f5c282
d8a0f0f4bba5b13e9bdaa5fcd29005d226c448/netCDF4-1.4.2.tar.gz#sha256=b934af350459c
f9041bcdf5472e2aa56ed7321c018d918e9f325ec9a1f9d1a30
Processing netCDF4-1.4.2.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-9mh252\netCDF4-1.4.2\setup.c
fg
Running netCDF4-1.4.2\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\hp\appdata\local
\temp\easy_install-9mh252\netCDF4-1.4.2\egg-dist-tmp-6w8pii
reading from setup.cfg...

    HDF5_DIR environment variable not set, checking some standard locations ..
checking C:\Users\HP ...
checking /usr/local ...
checking /sw ...
checking /opt ...
checking /opt/local ...
checking /usr ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 126, in <module>
    sources=['rvic/clib/rvic_convolution.c'])])
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py",
 line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py",
 line 117, in do_egg_install
    cmd.run()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install
.py", line 391, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install
.py", line 621, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install
.py", line 672, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install
.py", line 717, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", lin
e 826, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", lin
e 1092, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", lin
e 1104, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install
.py", line 640, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install
.py", line 670, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install
.py", line 850, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install
.py", line 1078, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install
.py", line 1064, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 24
6, in run_setup
    raise
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 19
5, in setup_context
    yield
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 16
6, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 14
1, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 15
4, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 19
5, in setup_context
    yield
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 24
3, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 27
3, in run
    return func()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 24
2, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 46
, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-9mh252\netCDF4-1.4.2\setup.p
y", line 371, in <module>

  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-9mh252\netCDF4-1.4.2\setup.p
y", line 319, in _populate_hdf5_info

ValueError: did not find HDF5 headers
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107298/cannot-install-netcdf4-python-package-on-os-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install netCDF4 python package on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107298/cannot-install-netcdf4-python-package-on-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by downloading the wheel and then directing pip to it.

```
pip install <path to .whl>
```

I downloaded the wheel from [here](https://pypi.org/project/netCDF4/1.5.7/#files)